# rqt_console: command not found

Tags: ros2

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and I have `rqt` and `rqt_graph` but no `rqt_console`. I downloaded the debian package of Humble Hawksbill (humble) from the ROS 2 website to install. Any help is appeciated.

```
$ apt list | grep humble | grep rqt | grep console
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
ros-humble-rqt-console/jammy,now 2.0.2-3jammy.20230919.222718 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-humble-rqt-py-console/jammy,now 1.0.2-3jammy.20230919.222731 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

Please execute the `rqt_console` via the ROS interface as shown below:

```
$ source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
$ ros2 run rqt_console rqt_console
```

A window should pop up as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

As always, please feel free to go through [the official documentation (for ROS 2 Humble)](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-CLI-Tools/Using-Rqt-Console/Using-Rqt-Console.html).